# Karate UI automation: How can I read content of generated PDF/word/excel file using Karate UI automation

Tags: karate

I have one UI Web application where I am automating my application with karate and target browser is chrome. there is one module which generate Report in form of PDF, word, excel and crystal report on same webpage where user is logged-in.

I am doing automation with Karate only. Does any one tried how to read content of such file using karate. any input will be very helpful for me.

I was reading https://intuit.github.io/karate/examples/ui-test/ and https://intuit.github.io/karate/karate-robot/ but i did not get anything that can help me.

Note: Here I don't need to download the report and validate on same place.